# Vim doesn't respect fileformat setting on windows share [Solved]

Tags: linux, windows, vim, gvfs

I have mounted several SMB shares (folders are located on windows server) on my linux machine

```
gvfs-mount smb://user@domain@fileserver/sharedfolder
```

I can access files and edit them in vim, but vim enforces fileformat=unix on save. `:set ff=dos` affect anything. On local files there is no problem.

**Update:** It turned out that the cause was the old version Shougo/vimfiler plugin. It was not so clear for me at first because I very seldom use this plugin, not for opening remote files especially.

Just update Vimfiler plugin from repo. Preserving fileformat in Vim is working fine now.

Comment: What file paths does Vim show for opened files?

Comment: File path showed in vim: '/run/user/1685001118/gvfs/smb-share:server=fileserver,share=sharedfolder,user=user%40domain/testpf.txt'

Comment: That looks okay, I was thinking it might have been using its own SMB access instead of GNOME's.

Comment: @AMasz : You can put `:au BufWrite *.* :set ff=unix` in your `~/.vimrc`.And try. It might solve the problem